# Can notification from addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask be canceled?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have simple global monitor for mouse clicks:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event){
    if ([event type] == NSLeftMouseDown) {
        [self mouseDown];
        if (self.lockMouse) {
            // Cancel event
        }
    }
}];
```

Is there any way to cancel global mouse events, so clicking only notifies my app?
I.e.: After clicking on any button on screen (that don't belong to my app) while "locked", event goes here, but not to button that was below cursor. Something like event.preventDefault() in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with this API, no.  From the documentation, it says that the block is:

> The event handler block object. It is passed the event to monitor. You are unable to change the event, merely observe it.

If you want to intercept the event and prevent it from propagating, you need to use a `CGEventTap` instead.

Comment: In this scenario, I fixed it by showing transparent, fullscreen window below cursor and using it to capture all clicks :)